# Typescript generic type in class constructor's argument

Tags: typescript

I am trying to implement repository generic pattern using facebook dataloader.

This code is for a GraphQL API.

Abstract base class, were I get the error:

```js
import { Collection, Db, InsertOneWriteOpResult, ObjectId } from "mongodb";
import { RepositoryGeneric } from "../../types/database";

export default abstract class BaseRepository<TEntity, TLoaders> implements RepositoryGeneric<TEntity> {
    protected mongoCollection: Collection<TEntity>;
    protected dataLoaders: TLoaders;

    public constructor(database: Db, collection: string, loaders: TLoaders) {
        this.mongoCollection = database.collection(collection);
        this.dataLoaders = loaders;
    }

    public async findOne(id: ObjectId | string): Promise<TEntity | null> {
        if (typeof id === "string") {
            id = ObjectId.createFromHexString(id);
        }

        // This line is producing the error
        return this.dataLoaders.id.load(id);
    }

    public async create(entity: TEntity): Promise<TEntity> {
        const result: InsertOneWriteOpResult = await this.mongoCollection.insertOne(entity);

        if (!result.result.ok) {
            throw new Error();
        }

        return result.ops[0];
    }
}
```

Class extending the abstract base class:

```js
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";
import { EntityBusiness } from "../../types/database";
import BusinessLoaders from "../loaders/businessLoaders";
import BaseRepository from "./baseRepository";

export default class BusinessRepository extends BaseRepository<EntityBusiness, BusinessLoaders> {
    public constructor(mongoClient: MongoClient, businessLoaders: BusinessLoaders) {
        super(mongoClient.db(), "business", businessLoaders);

        // tslint:disable-next-line: no-console
        console.log(businessLoaders.id);
    }
}
```

Class implementing the dataloader:

```js
import DataLoader from "dataloader";
import { AggregationCursor, Collection, MongoClient, ObjectId } from "mongodb";
import { EntityBusiness, LoaderCommon } from "../../types/database";

export default class BusinessLoaders implements LoaderCommon<EntityBusiness> {
    private idLoader: DataLoader<ObjectId, EntityBusiness>;

    public constructor(mongoClient: MongoClient) {
        this.idLoader = new DataLoader((keys) => this.idBatch(mongoClient, keys), {
            cacheKeyFn: (key) => key.toHexString(),
        });
    }

    public get id(): DataLoader<ObjectId, EntityBusiness> {
        return this.idLoader;
    }

    private async idBatch(mongoClient: MongoClient, keys: ObjectId[]): Promise<EntityBusiness[]> {
        const collection: Collection<EntityBusiness> = mongoClient.db().collection("business");
        const aggregation: AggregationCursor<EntityBusiness> = collection.aggregate([
            { $match: { _id: { $in: keys } } },
            { $addFields: { __order: { $indexOfArray: [keys, "$_id"] } } },
            { $sort: { __order: 1 } },
            { $project: { __order: 0 } },
        ]);

        return aggregation.toArray();

    }
}
```

I don't have so much experience with typescript but I expect no errors. Instead I get error:

> error TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'TLoaders'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to specify that your generic type has some constraints, specifically that it has an `id` property.  You can do that with the `extends` keyword inside the generic type definition:

```
interface ILoadersInterface<TEntity> {
  id: DataLoader<ObjectId, TEntity | null>
}

export default abstract class BaseRepository<TEntity, TLoaders extends ILoadersInterface<TEntity>> 
  implements RepositoryGeneric<TEntity> {
    // ...
}
```

More generally, a class needs to have enough type information inside itself to correctly resolve all code usage, since in this case TypeScript is not able to infer by usage that `TLoaders` will have an `id` property.  Conceptually, you can imagine that a generic type parameter is roughly `unknown` unless you specify a constraint like `extends Interface`, `extends string`, etc.

Comment: Thanks you, works fine. But then not is better use the interface directly?
`export default abstract class BaseRepository<TEntity> 
  implements RepositoryGeneric<TEntity> {
    protected dataLoaders: ILoadersInterface<TEntity>;
      public constructor(database: Db, collection: string, loaders: ILoadersInterface<TEntity>) {
        // ...
      }
}`

Comment: That also works.  The generic `extends` is probably more useful if you want to change the return value of something, that way you could have it return `TLoaders` from one of the methods and that return value would return the full type that was substituted into `TLoaders` and pick up the `id` property from `ILoadersInterface` plus any additional properties that might be defined.